# Another way of time increment

Tags: java

A method has been written that increments time in minutes that simulates how much time it takes to process item in a supermarket queue and if there is an empty queue, skip it and loops around to find the number of items processed in each interval (each time a minute has passed). I was wondering if there are ways to improve the code I have written?? Any help is much appreciated.

```
public void incrementTime(double incLength) {

    time += incLength; // increment time

    double lambda = avgGrocPerMin * incLength;
  Random rand = new Random();

    // loop through each queue
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

       if (lines[i].isEmpty()) {   // skip empty queues
           continue;
        }

        // loop to find number of groceries processed in interval
       int k = 0;
       double prob = rand.nextDouble();
       while (true) {
          // calc probability of exactly k groceries during interval (Poisson dist.) 
          double probK = Math.pow(lambda, k) * Math.exp(-lambda) / factorial(k);
          if (probK <= prob) { // increment k until cumulative probability, prob, reached
             k++;
             prob -= probK;
          } else {
             break;
          }
       }

       while (!lines[i].isEmpty() && k > 0) {
            lines[i].decFront(); // decrement grocery count
            k--;
       }
    }
    this.display();
}
```

Comment: If the code works then this question is more suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), otherwise please clarify your issue

Comment: I didn't know what to post it under, sorry.